# How to scroll to the last element in the list where list size keeps on increasing

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want selenium to scroll to the last element on the list. I have used both of these ways:

```
// 1.
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.END);

// 2.
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
        .executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

but they do not work as I'm scrolling on a modal window and they are not being executed successfully (I have tried hard and I know they do work but not in my case). I have also used this way of making xpath:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(//*[@class='Abc')[last()]));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
        .executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

This way I can only reach somewhere in the middle of the list, Because the problem here is that all the list elements do not load at once but they keep on loading as as we keep scrolling down and list size keeps on increasing. I want all the list elements loaded.

Comment: Can you use a while loop scroll down and pause for 3 seconds then query your position on the page and repeat if necessary?

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere That seems very difficult to me at the moment.

Comment: Have you checked if the website provides a web API to accomplish getting the data you need?

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll to the latest list element and save the results to array list and then scroll again until your last scroll give you the same array list length as previous scroll.

```
List<IWebElement> elsFoundTotal = new List<IWebElement>();
....
elsFoundNow = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("xxx"));

yourScrollFunction();

while(elsFoundTotal<elsFoundNow.count()){
 elsFoundNow = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("xxx"));
 elsFoundTotal = elsFoundNow;
 yourScrollFunction();
 elsFoundNow = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("xxx"));
}
```

Code is in c#, you can adapt it to java

Comment: Can you please write a code for that. thank you. @Herahadi

Comment: Okay. I have added the sample code above.I successfully use this concept to scroll on Instagram follower lists. Hope its help.